# How do I see the BSSID of the Wifi AP I'm previously connected to in Windows?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, cmd.exe

How do I see the BSSID of the Wifi AP I'm previously connected to in Windows?

In a command promp
**`netsh wlan show profile=name`**
shows only ssid and profile name and key

In a command promp
**`netsh wlan show interfaces`**
shows only bssid of current network

Is their any way to find bssid of **previously** connected network using cmd in windows???

Answer (score 0):

The command you are looking might be this:

> netsh wlan show profile

It will display a list of wifi networks you have created a profile for. If you add an asterisk at the end, it will also display detailed information about the various networks.